# Access a variable using a counter as part of the variable name

Tags: php, variables

I tried to do somthing like that:

```
$cat1 = array('hello', 'everyone');
$cat = array('bye', 'everyone');

for($index = 0; $index < 2; $index++) {
echo $cat$index[1];
}
```

It doesn't work of course.
What do I need to change here?

Comment: Why are you not using nested arrays?

Comment: Please go back to your questions and mark the best answer.

Comment: This is one of those examples where one *should* suggest a better, alternative solution instead of a direct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use nested arrays, but this can be done.

```
$cat1 = array('hello', 'everyone');
$cat2 = array('bye', 'everyone');

for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    echo ${'cat' . $i}[1];
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/language.variables.variable

This would be much better though:

```
$cats = array(
    array('hello', 'everyone'),
    array('bye', 'everyone')
);
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    echo $cat[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you intended?

```
$cat0 = array('hello', 'everyone');
$cat1 = array('bye', 'everyone');

for($index = 0; $index < 2; $index++) {
    $varname = 'cat'.$index;
    echo $varname[0].' '.$varname[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *insist* on doing it this way...

```
echo ${'cat' . $index}[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

To echo elements inside arrays, you need to be using

`echo $cat[$index]`

with your example.

I'm not sure what the `$index[1]` is supposed to be doing? Maybe I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference $index like that, it isn't an array.

```
echo $cat[$index];
```

is what you want to do.